# Can I use 'accommodating' as an opposite of 'dominating'?

Tags: antonyms

I thought that it is possible to use 'accommodating' as opposite of 'dominating'. But my co-worker did not agree with my argument:

> Suppose we are discussing about a specific topic we are trying to convince the other one. If I persuade you because of my power (e.g. I am in charge in that department), not because of acceptable reasons, I am dominating you. And this persuading will happen in a short time or a little more. And now if this pattern repeats many times in different situations with different dominant people I can say that you are accommodating.

Or is my argument totally wrong?

Comment: "accommodating" (considerate · friendly · generous · helpful · hospitable · polite · unselfish · obliging...) isn't really the opposite of "dominating / domineering" (imperative, imperious, masterful, peremptory,...). By and large, we only use "accommodating" to refer to the *senior* party in an interaction (who has the power to refuse whatever the junior party wants, but chooses not to exercise that power).

Comment: If there are two "social equals" who often disagree, but one of them is much more likely than the other to "concede" whatever point they disagree on, you might say the one who usually gives in is ***[com]pliant***.

Answer (score 1):

I'd have to agree with your coworker - 'accomodating' doesn't really seem to be a direct antonym of 'dominating'. They might describe two opposite kinds of people, but the specific meanings are not directly antonymic.

In the context of your example, where 'dominating' means asserting power and forcing opinions onto other people, I'd say that '*yielding*' might be a better antonym - it means 'disposed to submit or comply'. A yielding person listens to others and is willing to go along with what they think. Another possibility, is 'disobliging', which means to refuse or neglect the wishes of others, although this is not a word commonly used in everyday speech.

Answer (score 0):

[M-W "appeasing"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/appease)

> **1 :** pacify, conciliate especially : to make concessions to (someone, such as an aggressor or a critic) often at the sacrifice of principles

[M-W "submissive"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/submissive)

> submitting to others

[M-W "concilatory](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conciliatory):

> intended to gain goodwill or favor or to reduce hostility : tending or intended to conciliate